# Project-wide properties to Java

Tags: gradle

I'm writing some multi-module Android app (actually in Kotlin) and I'd like to have some project-wide flags. I was thinking about setting those flags in Gradle and accessing them from my code. But I couldn't find how to do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a property file in Gradle which is added to your runtime classpath. Please adapt the following groovy/java to kotlin/android

```
ext {
    someProperty = 'xxx' 
} 
dependencies {
    compile files("$buildDir/generated/resources")
}
task generateResources {
    // configure task inputs/outputs for up-to-date checking/caching 
    inputs.property("someProperty", someProperty) 
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/generated/resources"
    doLast {
         file("$buildDir/generated/resources/myprops.properties").text = "someProperty=$someProperty"
    }
 }
 // important: wire the task into the DAG 
 compileJava.dependsOn generateResources
```

Then in your java code

```
InputStream in = MyClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myprops.properties");
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(in) 
String someProperty = props getProperty("someProperty"); // xxx
```